# How to loop through files in a directory having a certain word in filename using bash script?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to loop through all the files in a directory which contain a certain word in filename using bash script.

The following script loops through all the files in the directory,

```
cd path/to/directory

for file in *
do
  echo $file
done
```

`ls | grep 'my_word'` gives only the files which have the word 'my_word' in the filename. However I'm unsure how to replace the * with ls | grep 'my_word' in the script.

If i do like this,

```
for file in ls | grep 'my_word'
do
  echo $file
done
```

It gives me an error "syntax error near unexpected token `|'". What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The correct syntax would be `for file in $(ls | grep 'my_word'); do`, but using `find` or a glob` is still the correct way to go.

Comment: yes, thanks, figured that out later with the help of steve's answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should [avoid parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) where possible. Assuming there are no subdirectories in your present directory, a glob is usually sufficient:

```
for file in *foo*; do echo "$file"; done
```

---

If you have one or more subdirectories, you may need to use `find`. For example, to `cat` the files:

```
find . -type f -name "*foo*" | xargs cat
```

Or if your filenames contain special characters, try:

```
find . -type f -name "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and a [while loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html):

```
while IFS= read -r myfile; do echo "$myfile"; done < <(find . -type f -name '*foo*')
```

Or if your filenames contain special characters, try:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' myfile; do
  echo "$myfile"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*foo*' -print0)
```

Comment: thanks first one works. how do i use the second one in for loop? that's what i don't know. i want to substitute the function result in the place of *.

Comment: figured it out, files=`find . -type f -name "*my_word*" | xargs cat` and for file in $files works! thanks!

Comment: @Steve Is the no-parsing-`ls` thing a security issue? A file/dir name could be a command that sends all to oblivion?

Comment: @t0mgs: I wouldn't call it a security issue. Those problems exist when parsing any input. Parsing `ls` should just be avoided where possible, as the output can't always be trusted.